# Custom Share Open Graph Call not Shown on Timeline

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph

Error trying to post open graph story to Show on Timeline. Explicit sharing set and approved for open graph story. I have updated to 4.2 where i see in the change log "Fixed bug preventing usage of fb:explicitly_shared for open graph actions." I was hopeful this would fix the issue but none the less it has not.

Code used:

```
FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject *object = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject     objectWithProperties:properties];
FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction *action = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction alloc] init];
action.actionType = @"simplst:create";
[action setObject:object forKey:@"simplst"];
//i have tried all the following and none work
[action setObject:@"true" forKey:@"fb:explicitly_shared"];
//[action setObject:@(YES) forKey:@"fb:explicitly_shared"];
//[action setObject:@(1) forKey:@"fb:explicitly_shared"];
//[action setString:@"true" forKey:@"fb:explicitly_shared"];
//[action setValue:@(YES) forKey:@"fb:explicitly_shared"]; //this prevents    share

FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent *content = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent alloc] init];
content.action = action;
content.previewPropertyName = @"simplst";

FBSDKShareAPI *shareAPI = [[FBSDKShareAPI alloc] init];
shareAPI.delegate = self;
shareAPI.shareContent = content;
[shareAPI share];
```

The app can get a post id, og story shows in activity log, audience is friends, allowed on timeline is selected.

This open graph story has been approved with "Explicitly Shared" capability checked and displaying a green status for the open graph action.

This Stack question does not work [IOS Facebook SDK - Post Open Graph and show on Timeline without clicking Activity Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17310892/ios-facebook-sdk-post-open-graph-and-show-on-timeline-without-clicking-activit)

This Stack question does not have a working answer
[Open graph story posted successfully using graph API but not seen neither on the timeline nor in the Activity Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926716/open-graph-story-posted-succesfully-using-graph-api-but-not-seen-neither-on-the?lq=1)

This Stack post contains an answer from facebook stating there is no way to show the post on a user's timeline, even with explicitly shared set to true. [Explicitly Shared not working for post - Facebook Android SDK Open Graph Story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118894/explicitly-shared-not-working-for-post-facebook-android-sdk-open-graph-story)
So if this is still true, how do I share on a timeline (such as instagram)?

I have submitted a bug report as well. When I get this working, whatever the problem, I will document it.

Comment: can you share the bug report link here?

Comment: Have you figured this out yet? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: Yes. It is totally up to Facebook. If you have an approved open graph story, explicitly shared is set to 1 (true, yes), and previous stories have not been removed from your wall, then the Chances are extremely high it will show up on your wall.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having problems with OG posts showing on the timeline.  The this worked for me: [action setString:@"true" forKey:@"fb:explicitly_shared"];